Fill NA column with other variable by id if dectects a non-missing value a column R
I am trying to pass from something like this:

To this:

This is, filling the column seq with the values of m by id, after counter has a value different from missing
I tried with function fill from tidyr and the option down but not working. Thanks

Downvote for data object delivered as image.

I think this should work:
library(dplyr)

your_data |>
  mutate(
    seq = ifelse(cumsum(is.na(counter)) > 0, m, seq),
    .by = year
  )

I can't test this without input--a screenshot of your data doesn't work as input. If you run into any problems, please edit your question to make it reproducible by providing data for testing. The easiest way to do this is with dput(), dput(your_data[1:10, ]) will create copy/pasteable R code to reproduce the first 10 rows of your_data.
